# Concatenating in Pandas but keeping duplicate column names

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is there a way when concatenating a list of dataframes in pandas to keep duplicate columns. For example, I create a list of dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
Label1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A']
Label2 = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E']
Label3 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

row1 = [1, 2, 3, 5]
row2 = [2,4,5,6]
row3 = [5,10,22,33,44]

dflist = []

dflist.append(pd.DataFrame([row1], columns = Label1))
dflist.append(pd.DataFrame([row2], columns = Label2))
dflist.append(pd.DataFrame([row3], columns = Label3))
```

Label 1 element 4 will raise `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects` when I run `final_df = pd.concat(dflist)`. Is there a way to keep the duplicates. In this example I could easily change `A` to `A2` or something like that, but unfortunately I am dealing with hundreds of columns and cannot change them all.

Comment: Why do you want to have duplicate column names? You will not be able to access them by name in the future.

Comment: @DYZ Super dirty data from xml that I first need in python and then clean

Comment: You may want to rename columns before labeling them. I do not think there is another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing an append, do a merge function using 'outer' as the how method (instead of the default 'inner' method.  But before doing the merge, add a special column like 'merge_col' with a value that is unique in each LabelX data frame and then use this merge_col as the on column.

The merge function will uniquely identify columns with matching names from the source df's in the output df.

```
import pandas as pd
Label1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A']
Label2 = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E']
Label3 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

row1 = [1, 2, 3, 5]
row2 = [2,4,5,6]
row3 = [5,10,22,33,44]

df1 = pd.DataFrame([row1], columns = Label1)
df1['merge_col'] = 1
df2 = pd.DataFrame([row2], columns = Label2)
df2['merge_col'] = 2
df3 = pd.DataFrame([row3], columns = Label3)
df3['merge_col'] = 3

final_df = pd.merge(left=df1,right=df2,how='outer',on='merge_col')
final_df = pd.merge(left=final_df,right=df2,how='outer',on='merge_col')
```